# Is it possible to back up network devices configs on a RADIUS server (automatically or manual)

Tags: radius

My question is about back up on RADIUS server. Is it possible to back up network devices configs on a RADIUS server (automatically or manual)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Radius is a networking protocol, aimed at  Authentication, Authorization, and Accounting.

It is not designed to backup configurations.

Now a device that can act as a Radius server may be able to perform other roles, like a FTP server on which a network device can backup is config, especially if you radius server is Linux or Windows machine. But this has nothing to do with Radius itself. It would be two different services that happen to be hosted on the same device.

Comment: It's worth noting that it is common to use the same server for the two purposes (RADIUS, backups), if only because that server already has confidential data on it, and the backups of that server need to be kept confidential.